# What part of speech is 'Hearing' in these sentences?

Tags: parts-of-speech, progressive-aspect, nonfinite-verbs

What is *hearing* in these sentences?

1. Hearing the voice, the boy woke up.
2. The boy woke up hearing the voice.

Comment: It's a number of things. It's a present participle, for one thing. It's also a transitive verb form (it has a direct object _the voice_), with a missing subject, assumed to be _the boy_. The participle clause (or phrase) _hearing the voice_ functions as an adverb of circumstance and therefore can go at the beginning (with comma intonation) or at the end of the sentence. What kind of answer were you looking for? Oh, and by the way, asking about parts of speech of individual words  is not a good idea; concentrate on the constructions they're in -- that's what grammar is about.

Comment: It's undoubtedly a verb functioning as predicator in the clause "hearing the voice", which functions as an adjunct of implicated reason: it gives a reason for the matrix situation.

Comment: @JohnLawler It's hard to show what constructions they are if you don't know any of the parts of speech!

Comment: @Araucaria: It's even harder when you know all 8 parts of speech.

Comment: @JohnLawler I thought they'd recently discovered number 118.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth They did, but unfortunately it was remarkably short-lived.

Comment: @tchrist Is the infinitive-marking particle _to_ a fermion or a boson?

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> It's a number of things.
>
> It's a present participle, for one thing.
>
> It's also a transitive verb form (it has a direct object *the voice*),
>   with a missing subject, assumed to be *the boy*.
>
> The participle clause (or phrase) *hearing the voice* functions as an
>   adverb of circumstance and therefore can go at the beginning (with
>   comma intonation) or at the end of the sentence.
>
> What kind of answer were you looking for? Oh, and by the way, asking
>   about parts of speech of individual words  is not a good idea;
>   concentrate on the constructions they're in – *that*'s what grammar is
>   about.